# What is the name of this 3D shape with 12 outer vertices?

Tags: geometry, terminology, 3d, solid-geometry

Faces: 48

Outside vertices: 12

Other vertices: 14 (I believe)
[image: Object]

Comment: Am I seeing the shape correctly to think that this is essentially three $8$-sided dice merged?

Comment: @abiessu I thought so, but [apparently not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_of_three_octahedra). Well, not regular ones, at least.

Comment: @Arthur: ah, so close.  At least I can say I was in the ballpark...

Comment: And if anyone wanted to know, and didn't already, this is a common [wooden star puzzle](https://www.amazon.com/Monkey-Pod-Games-Star-Puzzle/dp/B0012NYQJK). (Amazon link just because all the others I found had spoilers on how to solve it...)

Comment: See this video for examples of puzzles based on this figure, tessellations of the star, and folding a cube into two stars! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWgXlvIlpzM

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The object is the [first stellation of the rhombic dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_stellation_of_rhombic_dodecahedron).
[image]
This is sometimes known as Escher's solid, for its use in a study for his *Stars*, though the final picture uses [a compound of three *regular* octahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_of_three_octahedra) rather than the squashed ones of this question's solid.